# BeautifulSoup / lxml: Are there problems with large elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml, activepython

```
import os, re, sys, urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hoerzu.de/tv-programm/jetzt/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"block"})
print len(divs)
```

Output:

```
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, re, sys, urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import lxml
>>>
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hoerzu.de/tv-programm/jetzt/")
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
>>> divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"block"})
>>> print len(divs)
2
```

I also tried:

```
divs = soup.find_all(class_="block")
```

with same result ...

But there are 11 elements that fit this condition. So are there any limitations such as max element size resp. how can I get all the elements?

Comment: I guess you wanted to go to bed...

Comment: I got 11 divs with your code.

Comment: Same as @JosefAssad I'm getting 11 with your first code

Comment: So this is maybe a python version issue or what? For me using ActivePython 2.7.2.5 I'm getting only 2 every time and I really don't know how to fix that :(

Comment: Tried it now with Python 3.2.2.2, too --> same results ... also tried it on different pcs --> same results ... can you pls tell me your trick?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is probably using the 'html.parser' instead of 'lxml':

```
import os, re, sys, urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hoerzu.de/tv-programm/jetzt/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"block"})
print len(divs)
```

With your original code (using `lxml`) it printed `1` for me, but this prints `11`. `lxml` is lenient but not as lenient as `html.parser` for this page.

Please note that the page has over *one thousand* warnings if you run it through `tidy`. Including invalid character codes, unclosed `<div>`s, letters like `<` and `/` at positions they are not allowed.

Comment: Seems to be more an issue of beautifulsoup since plain lxml gets all divs, too and so I recently switched to plain lxml.